# In Opera (10.63), do the comment fonts support bold and italic?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

I just posted a comment to [this Raiders question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7919/1361), and **bolded** a few words - which show no changes. (I also just bolded "bolded", which isn't showing up here either :(

Does the font used for comments on the main site display bold/italics in the Opera browser (V10.63)? (It does work in Firefox).

And unrelated to browsers, is black-on-white a good choice for meta's text? (Personally I can't stand it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do see it bolded. See: regular vs **bold**, REGULAR vs **BOLD**

Bold is a little whiter on meta posts it is probably not that visible on smaller text. It is not very visible indeed. Can you see it in my all caps example?

Also, bold text is quite visible in comments of the linked question, a lot more than here anyway.

If you don't see it at all, maybe it is a browser issue. Which browser are you using?

EDIT: As OP said in a comment, it turns out it is an issue with Opera.

Comment: Sigh... you're right, it's an Opera problem - In Firefox it shows fine. Should I modify the question to mention Opera, or (try to) delete it? :)

Comment: @JohnC: Don't delete it. Just include that it is about Opera. It is still a bug. Nice catch, btw!

Answer (score 2):

In Opera 11.60, this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Sigh... I have 10.63, haven't updated yet.